# Why Bell's state can be prepared?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

This is a basic question, I am new to Quantum Computation and want to ask where my reasoning is wrong.

In the [lecture notes](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1617/QuantComp/slides5.pdf#8) it is stated that a Bell's state $|\beta_{zx}\rangle$ can be "prepared" as follows:

$$|\beta_{zx}\rangle = \textrm{CNOT} \cdot (H \otimes I) \cdot |z,x\rangle$$

But isn't it the case that:

- $|z,x\rangle$ being a shorthand for $|z\rangle\otimes|x\rangle$ is a product state $p$
- $\textrm{CNOT} \cdot (H \otimes I)$ is essentially some matrix $M$
- Thus the $\textrm{RHS}$ is a product state because it equals to $M \cdot p.$
- Whereas $\textrm{LHS}$ is the entangled Bell's state.

So how can $\textrm{LHS}$ equal $\textrm{RHS}$?

Comment: Your wrong assumption is that multiplying a product state by a matrix yields another product state. This is only true if the matrix itself can be written as a tensor product. For a CNOT gate this is not the case.

Comment: No. You should leave it. Other people may also find it useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Thus the $\textrm{RHS}$ is a product state because it equals to $M \cdot p.$"

This part is wrong. It is not necessarily the case that multiplying product state by a matrix gives another product state.